# Update mysql timezone for Pacific/Fiji

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, timezone

My mysql  **Pacific/Fiji** Timezone is ahead by an hour. How can I possibly update this. My mysql server is on Ubuntu. Tried below technique and it didnt work.

mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -u root -p mysql

Appreciate your assistance. The time on my server is reflected correctly when using Pacific/Fiji. Only issue is with mysql timezone

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue by adjusting the timezone through my code in the application. Could'nt find a systematic way to adjust the Pacific/Fiji timezone.